# How do I change the date format with an echo?

Tags: php, date, echo

```
echo "<p>These are the available venues for $date that also have the catering 
grade of <b>$catering_grade </b> </p>";
```

This is what it comes up with:

*These are the available venues for **2014-05-13** that also have the catering grade of 3*

How do I change the format to be DD/MM/YYYY within the echo?

Comment: is `$catering_grade` coming from the db ? if so I'd suggest using `DATE_FORMAT` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format in the query

Answer (score 0):

You need

[`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date()`](http://php.net/date):

```
$originalDate = "2014-05-13";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

[<kbd>**Working Demo**</kbd>](http://codepad.org/LblSTqik)

So in your VIEW

```
 <?php
echo "<p>These are the available 
venues for " . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date)) . " that 
also have the catering 
grade of <b>$catering_grade </b> </p>";
?>
```

[<kbd>**Working Demo**</kbd>](http://codepad.org/EW3l5prI)

Comment: echo "<p>These are the available venues for:" echo $date."
    </br>";
    $date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date));
    //$date = $date[2]."-".$date[0]."-".$date[1];

    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $day = date('l', $timestamp);
    echo " <p> that also have the catering grade of 
    <b>$catering_grade </b> </p>";
what is wrong with this code as it comes up with 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting ',' or ';'

Answer (score 0):

```
date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date));
```

> OR

```
$date = '2010-05-13';
$date = str_replace('-', '/', $date);
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
```